# get dom changes with simple-html-dom

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom, simple-html-dom

want get dom with his javascript changes like slider jquery plugin .

before slider effect on dom it's like below :

```
 <div id="slides">
<img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
<img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
<img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
<img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
<img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
```

and after

```
 <div id="slides">
<li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/940x528"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/940x528"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/940x528"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/940x528"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/940x528"></a></li>
```

can get secound with simple-html-dom  ?

Comment: No, simple html dom is a html parser, not a javascript engine.

Comment: and if i want get source of a webpage like 2 example , what do for this ?

Comment: Probably a full browser solution like selenium.